# Automatic "In" and "Out" functions in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Just wondering if anyone knows if you can create functions and attach them to frame column type in Pandas so they are called automatically when you append or access data.

**My scenario -** I'm working with non-linear data Decibels, I would like to convert non-linear to a linear form so standard and existing python/pandas math can be used. For example, 80dB + 80dB is ~83.0103dB (-not 160dB).

So what I'm interested in if we can write the "in" and "out" functions and applying them to the column type (say "dB") so they are stored internally as linear data, 80dB = 100000000(in linear form).  When you insert or append data the "in" function applied and the "out" function is applied to a dataframe when you access the data.  This conversion becomes transparent and allows users to focus on value rather than remembering to do conversions.

Thoughts?  Examples?

Much Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you'd want to subclass DataFrame and/or define a custom dtype. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html for the latter.  Also look into Python "accessor" and "magic" methods. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/accessor-and-mutator-methods-in-python/ can get you started on accessors.  The "magic" methods will help with making operations transparent.

Comment: @SarahMesser - I was originally going to create some functions myself and use a decorator around the float type which could do the translations for me but then realized I probably want to use Pandas for much of my processing.  I'm new to Pandas so was looking for a little inspiration on how to approach it.

The Pandas decorator might be what I'm looking for.